# PESDK not running in released version only run in debug apk error occurring in released apk

Tags: android, photoeditorsdk

the below crash occurs after selecting image from gallery app crash  not running in released version any one can help me on this

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.photoeditorsdk.android.app, PID: 22149
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.photoeditorsdk.android.app/ly.img.android.pesdk.ui.activity.PhotoEditorActivity}:
> java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<ly.img.android.pesdk.utils.j> has no zero argument
> constructor
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3479)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3651)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2104)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<ly.img.android.pesdk.utils.j> has no zero argument
> constructor
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at b4.i.c(SourceFile:29)
> at b4.i.(SourceFile:4)
> at
> ly.img.android.pesdk.ui.model.state.UiConfigText.(SourceFile:3)
> at t4.d.createFromParcel(SourceFile:195)
> at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3284)
> at b4.u.(SourceFile:6)
> at x3.m.createFromParcel(SourceFile:64)
> at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3284)
> at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3177)
> at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3575)
> at
> android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
> at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
> at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1001)
> at o4.p.v(SourceFile:66)
> at
> ly.img.android.pesdk.ui.activity.EditorActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:1)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8109)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8083)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3452)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3651) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2104) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)

It runs without crash in debug apk not run in released version